# Pyspark is trying to convert column to bool. Why?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, facebook-prophet

I have some SQL that creates a temp table:

```
%sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW MyTempTable AS 
select
  SaleDate,
  Count(salesId) as count_of_sales
from
  myviews.completed_sales
where
  SaleDate between '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
  and '2020-12-31 23:59:59'
group by
  SaleDate
```

This gives me the following results: a sample

| SaleDate | count_of_sales |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-12-20 | 20 |
| 2020-11-21 | 83 |
| 2020-10-20 | 6 |
| 2020-09-01 | 1365 |
| 2020-08-20 | 408 |

I then want to send this to a dataframe and begin using fbprophet model:

```
import pyspark
import pandas as pd
from fbprophet import Prophet
df = spark.table('MyTempTable')
#display(df)


# instantiate the model and set parameters
model = Prophet(
    interval_width=0.95,
    growth='linear',
    daily_seasonality=False,
    weekly_seasonality=True,
    yearly_seasonality=True,
    seasonality_mode='multiplicative'
)

# fit the model to historical data
model.fit(df)
```

I get the following error when I try to run it:

```
ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.
```

update: Full error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-4274713499654188> in <module>
     17 
     18 # fit the model to historical data
---> 19 model.fit(df)
     20 

/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fbprophet/forecaster.py in fit(self, df, **kwargs)
   1099             raise Exception('Prophet object can only be fit once. '
   1100                             'Instantiate a new object.')
-> 1101         if ('ds' not in df) or ('y' not in df):
   1102             raise ValueError(
   1103                 'Dataframe must have columns "ds" and "y" with the dates and '

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/column.py in __nonzero__(self)
    911 
    912     def __nonzero__(self):
--> 913         raise ValueError("Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', "
    914                          "'~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.")
    915     __bool__ = __nonzero__
```

Comment: I think fbprophet accepts pandas dataframe only, not spark

Comment: I use a pandas dataframe then: `df = pd.DataFrame` the new error now shows this new message: typeError: argument of type 'type' is not iterable

Comment: you just created an empty dataframe class...

Comment: please learn the basics of dataframes, pandas and spark before trying to use something like fbprophet

Comment: right.. yeah my mistake.

Comment: when you say accepts pandas dataframe only, not spark. Are you saying that I am not using pandas dataframes? I don't understand

Comment: yes... @daveswans

Comment: Ok so I found that you can use the following and it will work `pandasDF = df.toPandas()`